# Get a single accelerometer value

Tags: android, accelerometer

I'm working on adding a calibration feature to an accelerometer-driven game. For the calibration, I need a single value from the accelerometer. Should I register a listener, get the first value it gives me, and unregister it, or is there a better way to get just one value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically there is no way to do get a single value as far as I can tell. What I ended up doing is putting in a variable called `lastAccelValue` and registering my Activity to listen for accelerometer updates at the slowest possible speed. Each new accelerometer value is stored to `lastAccelValue`.

Answer (score -1):

This should help:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getSensorList%28int%29

You simply get sensors which you are interested in and read their values.

Comment: I can get a `Sensor` object, but how can I get a reading?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html

Comment: getResolution() or getPower() method.

Comment: Neither of those return the sensor's value. getPower returns the number of milliamps the sensor is using and getResolution returns the sensors accuracy.